# Is there a weather indicator?

Tags: indicator

I recently replaced the indicators in the gnome panel with the **Indicator Applet Complete**, as can be seen in the screenshot below.

[image]

However I really miss the weather which used to be displayed with the date gnome applet. I tried searching for an alternative weather **indicator** and found one [here](http://www.webupd8.org/2010/07/install-weather-indicator-applet-with.html). However its ppa is empty and no longer works.

Is there any other alternative? I prefer it being an **indicator** rather than a ordinary gnome applet as I already know that there is one that can be added to the gnome panel (screenshot below for more info)

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is

[indicator-weather](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/indicator-weather) [image: Install indicator-weather]

After installing, you can start the indicator by running `indicator-weather`. Keep an eye on their [project page](https://launchpad.net/weather-indicator/) for updates!

---

To make the indicator start automatically:

- Go to *System → Preferences → Startup Applications* (Or *Applications → Startup Applications* if you're on Unity)
- Click *Add* and select `indicator-weather` as the command.

To quit it, run `killall indicator-weather` in a Terminal. (Check if it doesn't start automatically after installing from the PPA below, I'm not sure)