# Seeing the weather again in the "current time bar" on Ubuntu 11.04

Tags: weather

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a weather indicator?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/21348/is-there-a-weather-indicator)

Ok , so until now I was able to see the current weather in my city directly in the top panel, included in the time bar. However, with the update this is no longer possible. Is there a way to restore this?

Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

There is an indicator-weather you can find it here
 http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2011/02/indicator-weather-puts-temperature-on-panel/