# How do I display the current local temp.?

Tags: system-tray

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a weather indicator?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/21348/is-there-a-weather-indicator)

Before I updated to 12.04, right next to the clock it used to display my current local outdoor temp.  Is there a way to get that back?  I found it to be very useful.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, from the terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install indicator-weather
```

Or available through the Ubuntu Software Center:

[indicator-weather](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/indicator-weather) [image: Install indicator-weather]