# How do I show the outside temperature in the indicator bar?

Tags: 13.10, indicator, temperature, weather

I recently moved onto 13.10. After the upgrade, the current weather was no longer displayed with an indicator. How do I get that back?

I've seen one [potential duplicate](https://askubuntu.com/questions/21348/is-there-a-weather-indicator) but the `indicator-weather` package doesn't seem to exist any more (the apt link didn't run and Software Centre says there are no items with that name).

Comment: An alternative weather indicator is [MyWeatherIndicator](http://askubuntu.com/questions/30334/what-application-indicators-are-available/38004#38004).

Answer (score 1):

[Indicator-Weather](https://launchpad.net/weather-indicator) dev team started new series (2.0). It is available from their [Stable PPA](https://launchpad.net/~weather-indicator-team/+archive/ppa)

Daily build PPA is available too, Check [team page](https://launchpad.net/~weather-indicator-team).